# hiding access keys and tokens for client side JS libraries in Angular

Tags: angular, security, mixpanel, rollbar

For example, I am using Rollbar to track and log errors, and their JS documentation tells me to input the access token in the JS code. Anyone inspecting the source can find this token and call Rollbar using it.

```
// https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/angular
const rollbarConfig = {
  accessToken: 'POST_CLIENT_ITEM_TOKEN',
  captureUncaught: true,
  captureUnhandledRejections: true,
};
```

The same can be said of Mixpanel for analytics. I believe Google Analytics has a whitelist domain settings, which seems good enough.

As a general solution, how should I secure these client side libraries access tokens and keys?

It's a huge pain to move everything to the server side via API calls, but even if I do, it would only be secured via JWT tokens, so those will be valid until they expire, which isn't a real solution either.

Comment: In `Angular` there is `environment.ts` file where you can have all your configuration keys. During `--aot` this file will be bundled into build which is uglyfied and minified code

Comment: Yes my environment variables are in there now, but code being uglyfied and minified doesn't stop someone from pulling out the key if they want to really dig in and inspect the source.